# trying to fill a 2D array by user-input how to do it?

Tags: java, for-loop, user-input, multidimensional-array

i am creating a code that allow user to enter his input to create a 2D array but it did not work as it should i do not know where is the problem if anyone can help me i will appreciate that.

## this my code :

```
package test7;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class test7 {

    private int row = 4;
    private int col = 4;
    private int[][] matrix;

    public test7(int trow, int tcol) {

        this.row = trow;
        this.col = tcol;
    }

    public test7(int trow, int tcol, int[][] m) {

        this.row = trow;
        this.col = tcol;
        this.matrix = m;
    }
public int[][] fill(){


        int[][] data = new int[row][col];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int row = 0; row< matrix.length; row++){
            for(int col = 0 ;col< matrix[row].length; col++){
                System.out.println("enter the elementss for the Matrix");
                data[row][col] = in.nextInt();


            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return data;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] ma = new int[3][2];
        test7 q2 = new test7(3, 2,ma);
        q2.fill();
    }
}
```

## the output:

```
enter the elementss for the Matrix
4
enter the elementss for the Matrix
3

enter the elementss for the Matrix
5
enter the elementss for the Matrix

8

enter the elementss for the Matrix
9
enter the elementss for the Matrix
0
```

## the output should look exactly like this:

1 2

3 4

5 6

Comment: Your `fill` method does no filling.

Comment: how it does not fill ??  i thought that i am taking the user-input and added to the 2d array by using the for loop... isn't this right?

Comment: Which line specifically do you think is adding values to the array?

Comment: now i changed the code inside the for loop but now it display and error

Comment: @java dev, be specific, what error is displayed, how exactly you changed the code?

Comment: @AlexKM  i will edit my question and specify the changed code and the output error.

Comment: @javadev you dint get my answer properly. I have updated the answer with complete fill function so that there is no confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public int[][] fill(){
      int[][] data = new int[row][col];  
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) 

     .....

      return data; 

  }
```

You were declaring data array to length

```
 [0][0]
```

This is why the error is. Change the statement to above given code.

**UPDATE**

```
   public int[][] fill(){ 
        int[][] data = new int[row][col]; 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int row = 0; row< matrix.length; row++){ 
              for(int col = 0 ;col< matrix[row].length; col++){ 
                   System.out.println("enter the elementss for the Matrix"); 
                  data[row][col] = in.nextInt(); 
               } System.out.println(); 
          } 

           for(int row = 0; row< matrix.length; row++){
       for(int col = 0 ;col< matrix[row].length; col++){ 
             System.out.println(data[row][col]);
       } 
      System.out.println(); 
   }
         return data;
```

}

This will give you the desired output , add it to ***fill*** method before the ***return*** statement

Comment: yes i changed my code take a look on my updated question now i have another problem . it just enter number without displaying the 2d array i had displayed the last output

Comment: How do you want your outout to be?

Comment: i will edit my question again to display how it should look the output

Comment: this answer will build a 2d array but without using the user input what i want is to make the user enter the numbers to build it

Answer (score 1):

Replace your fill() method to this

```
   public int[][] fill(){
    int a[][]=new int[row][col];

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter the elementss for the Matrix");
    for(int row=0;row<3;row++){

        for(int col=0;col<3;col++){

            a[row][col]=input.nextInt();
            }
        }
return a;
}
```

**Reason:**

Your current `fill()` method is not saving values to the array
you must ad this line

```
 a[row][col]=input.nextInt();
```

using

```
  int x = in.nextInt();
           system.out.print(x);
```

you are just entering the data again and again on the `int` variable `x`

**Update**

change this

```
 int[][] data = new int[0][0];
```

to this

```
 int[][] data = new int[row][col];
```

Comment: yes now i understand the problem and i changed my code but now the system display another error:  **enter the elementss for the MatrixException in thread "main" 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at exam3Programing1_20_12_2010.Question2.fill(Question2.java:33)
 at exam3Programing1_20_12_2010.Question2.main(Question2.java:45)
**

Comment: why the system display **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** when i am starting from 0 and anding by the array.length-1 ??

Comment: why are you creating a new array with 0 length new int[0][0]; ??

Comment: ohhh it was this mistake...  but know it just enter the number without getting any creation for the array..i will update my question and display the last output after i changed my code take i look on it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("enter the elementss for the Matrix");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[][] data = new int[matrix.length][];//note the change here
    for(int i = 0; i< matrix.length; i++){
        data[i]=new int[matrix[i].length]; // note the the change here
        for(int j = 0 ;j< matrix[i].length; j++){
            data[i][j] = in.nextInt(); // note the change here
        }
        system.out.println();
    }
    return data;
```

Comment: i tried you solution but it give me an error   **enter the elementss for the Matrix
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at exam3Programing1_20_12_2010.Question2.fill(Question2.java:31)
 at exam3Programing1_20_12_2010.Question2.main(Question2.java:43)
**

Comment: @  Darshan Lila this answer will build a 2d array but without using the user input what i want is to make the user enter the numbers to build it

Comment: Do you want array of size specified by user?