# create 2-D character array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a character array like this one below:
[character array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1BTG.png)

i am unable to find a method . Please help me out. Beginner in java

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
char[][] x = new char[][]{};
x[0][1] = 'c';
```

...

Comment: thank you for the answer, can you tell how to build it by taking user inputs

Comment: @simoncowell Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132454/how-to-write-user-input-2d-array?noredirect=1&lq=1