# How to Sort Array and populate it

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

so I NEED to sort this array by column and populate it bu user input.
so this is my code and if you can help me it would be great..

```
public class JavaApplication45 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           
    String[][] AN = new String[8][5];

    AN[0][0] = "Curepipe";
    AN[0][1] = "-20.3162";
    AN[0][2] = "57.5166";
    AN[0][3] = "Plaine Wilhems";

    AN[1][0] = "Ebene";
    AN[1][1] = "-20.2456";
    AN[1][2] = ``"57.4842 ";
    AN[1][3] = "Plaine Wilhems ";

    AN[2][0] = "Rose Hill";
    AN[2][1] = "-20.2456";
    AN[2][2] = "57.4719";
    AN[2][3] = "Plaine Wilhems";

    AN[3][0] = "Beau Bassin";
    AN[3][1] = "-20.2276";
    AN[3][2] = "57.4681";
    AN[3][3] = "Plaine Wilhems";

    AN[4][0] = "Quatre Bornes";
    AN[4][1] = "-20.2654";
    AN[4][2] = "57.4778 ";
    AN[4][3] = "Plaine Wilhems";

    AN[5][0] = "Vacoas";
    AN[5][1] = "-20.2981";
    AN[5][2] = "57.4783";
    AN[5][3] = "Plaine Wilhems";

    AN[6][0] = "Mahebourg";
    AN[6][1] = "20.4081";
    AN[6][2] = "57.7000 ";
    AN[6][3] = "Grand Port    ";

    AN[7][0] = "Goodlands";
    AN[7][1] = "-20.0350";
    AN[7][2] = "57.6431";
    AN[7][3] = "Rivere du Rempart";


 int rows = 8;
    int columns = 4;
    int a, b;
    for (a = 0; a < rows; a++) {
        for (b = 0; b < columns; b++) {
            System.out.print(AN[a][b] + " \t");

        }
        System.out.println(" ");

    }
```

so I NEED to sort this array by column and populate it bu user input.
so this is my code and if you can help me it would be great..

Comment: Possibly related: [java Arrays.sort 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15452429), [trying to fill a 2D array by user-input how to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27654491)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code i understand that you want print 5 column which is `Postcode` i implemented this column dynamically as per your 2nd 2D array values, check out my code and it's output and confirm me is this answer useful to you or not

```
import java.util.*;

    public class JavaApplication45 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           
    String[][] AN = new String[8][5];

    AN[0][0] = "Curepipe";
    AN[0][1] = "-20.3162";
    AN[0][2] = "57.5166";
    AN[0][3] = "Plaine Wilhems";

    AN[1][0] = "Ebene";
    AN[1][1] = "-20.2456";
    AN[1][2] = "57.4842 ";
    AN[1][3] = "Plaine Wilhems ";

    AN[2][0] = "Rose Hill";
    AN[2][1] = "-20.2456";
    AN[2][2] = "57.4719";
    AN[2][3] = "Plaine Wilhems";

    AN[3][0] = "Beau Bassin";
    AN[3][1] = "-20.2276";
    AN[3][2] = "57.4681";
    AN[3][3] = "Plaine Wilhems";

    AN[4][0] = "Quatre Bornes";
    AN[4][1] = "-20.2654";
    AN[4][2] = "57.4778 ";
    AN[4][3] = "Plaine Wilhems";

    AN[5][0] = "Vacoas";
    AN[5][1] = "-20.2981";
    AN[5][2] = "57.4783";
    AN[5][3] = "Plaine Wilhems";

    AN[6][0] = "Mahebourg";
    AN[6][1] = "20.4081";
    AN[6][2] = "57.7000 ";
    AN[6][3] = "Grand Port    ";

    AN[7][0] = "Goodlands";
    AN[7][1] = "-20.0350";
    AN[7][2] = "57.6431";
    AN[7][3] = "Rivere du Rempart";
    
    //zip table
    String[][] str1 = new String[8][2];

    str1[0][0] = "Curepipe";
    str1[0][1] = "74415";

    str1[1][0] = "Goodlands";
    str1[1][1] = "30401";

    str1[2][0] = "Rose Hill";
    str1[2][1] = "71360";

    str1[3][0] = "Beau Bassin";
    str1[3][1] = "71401";

    str1[4][0] = "Vacoas";
    str1[4][1] = "73304";

    str1[5][0] = "Mahebourg";
    str1[5][1] = "50810";

    str1[6][0] = "Quatre Bornes";
    str1[6][1] = "72249";

    str1[7][0] = "Ebene";
    str1[7][1] = "72201";


    System.out.println("City     \tLat      \tlong      \tDistrict \t\tPostcode");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    int rows = 8;
    int columns = 5;
    int a, b, c;
    
    for (a = 0; a < rows; a++) {
        for (b = 0; b < columns; b++) {
            if(b<4){
                //use to formate values
                Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
                formatter.format( "%-7s",AN[a][b]);
                System.out.print(formatter + " \t");
            }else{
                for(c=0;c<rows;c++){
                    if(AN[a][0]==str1[c][0]){
                        if(AN[a][3].length()>14){
                        //use to formate values
                        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
                        formatter.format("%2s", str1[c][1]);
                        System.out.print(formatter + "  ");
                        }else{
                        //use to formate values
                        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
                        formatter.format("%13s", str1[c][1]);
                        System.out.print(formatter + "  ");
                        }
                        
                         
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
      
        System.out.println(" ");
        
    }
  }
     

}
```

**Output :**
[image]

Comment: now check i updated answer as per your formating request , if it is useful to you, you  
 can mark it as answer, thanks

Comment: why did you edit and change the question ? kindly mark my answer as answer and generate new question instead of edit the old one

Answer (score 1):

To sort by an arbitrary column, you can use `Comparator.comparing`.

```
int columnIndex = 0;
Arrays.sort(AN, Comparator.comparing(x -> x[columnIndex]));
```

To allow the user to enter the values for the array, you can use a `Scanner` to read input.

```
try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)){
    for(int i = 0; i < AN.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < AN[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print("Enter value: ");
            AN[i][j] = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Leo Happy to help.

Comment: Very good use of `Comparator`! The only concern I see with your answer is the use of `Scanner` with try-with-resources. The `Scanner` for `System.in` should not be closed; otherwise, `System.in` will also be closed and there is no way to reopen it without restarting the JVM. This will cause an exception if any other part of the application is using `System.in`. The `Scanner` for file is a good candidate to be used with try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static field to keep track of the sorted column (`sortField`). Each time you display the data, grab a the sorting instance with the current field.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class JavaApplication45 {
    static String[] fields = { "City", "Lat", "Long", "District", "Postcode" };
    static String[][] data;
    static String[][] zip;
    
    static String sortField;
    static Comparator<String[]> currentComparator;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        display();
        setSortField("City"); // Change the sorting...
        display();
    }
    
    private static void setSortField(String newSortField) {
        if (sortField != newSortField) {
            sortField = newSortField;
            currentComparator = generateComparator();
        }
    }
    
    private static void display() {
        Collection<String[]> lines = getCollection();
        if (currentComparator != null) {
            lines = lines.stream().sorted(currentComparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(fields).collect(Collectors.joining("\t")));
        System.out.println("-".repeat(60));     
        for (String[] line : lines) {
            System.out.println(Stream.of(line).collect(Collectors.joining("\t")));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    private static Collection<String[]> getCollection() {
        Collection<String[]> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
            String[] cols = new String[data[row].length + 1];
            for (int col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
                cols[col] = data[row][col];
            }
            cols[data[row].length] = zip[row][1];
            lines.add(cols);
        }
        return lines;
    }
    
    private static Comparator<String[]> generateComparator() {
        int sortIndex = Arrays.asList(fields).indexOf(sortField);
        return new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String[] left, String[] right) {
                return sortIndex != -1 ? left[sortIndex].compareTo(right[sortIndex]) : 0;
            }
        };
    }

    static {
        data = new String[8][4];
        
        data[0][0] = "Curepipe";
        data[0][1] = "-20.3162";
        data[0][2] = "57.5166";
        data[0][3] = "Plaine Wilhems";

        data[1][0] = "Ebene";
        data[1][1] = "-20.2456";
        data[1][2] = "57.4842";
        data[1][3] = "Plaine Wilhems ";

        data[2][0] = "Rose Hill";
        data[2][1] = "-20.2456";
        data[2][2] = "57.4719";
        data[2][3] = "Plaine Wilhems";

        data[3][0] = "Beau Bassin";
        data[3][1] = "-20.2276";
        data[3][2] = "57.4681";
        data[3][3] = "Plaine Wilhems";

        data[4][0] = "Quatre Bornes";
        data[4][1] = "-20.2654";
        data[4][2] = "57.4778";
        data[4][3] = "Plaine Wilhems";

        data[5][0] = "Vacoas";
        data[5][1] = "-20.2981";
        data[5][2] = "57.4783";
        data[5][3] = "Plaine Wilhems";

        data[6][0] = "Mahebourg";
        data[6][1] = "20.4081";
        data[6][2] = "57.7000";
        data[6][3] = "Grand Port";

        data[7][0] = "Goodlands";
        data[7][1] = "-20.0350";
        data[7][2] = "57.6431";
        data[7][3] = "Rivere du Rempart";

        zip = new String[8][2];

        zip[0][0] = "Curepipe";
        zip[0][1] = "74415";

        zip[1][0] = "Goodlands";
        zip[1][1] = "30401";

        zip[2][0] = "Rose Hill";
        zip[2][1] = "71360";

        zip[3][0] = "Beau Bassin";
        zip[3][1] = "71401";

        zip[4][0] = "Vacoas";
        zip[4][1] = "73304";

        zip[5][0] = "Mahebourg";
        zip[5][1] = "50810";

        zip[6][0] = "Quatre Bornes";
        zip[6][1] = "72249";

        zip[7][0] = "Ebene";
        zip[7][1] = "72201";
    }
}
```

### Output

```
City    Lat Long    District    Postcode
------------------------------------------------------------
Curepipe    -20.3162    57.5166 Plaine Wilhems  74415
Ebene   -20.2456    57.4842 Plaine Wilhems  30401
Rose Hill   -20.2456    57.4719 Plaine Wilhems  71360
Beau Bassin -20.2276    57.4681 Plaine Wilhems  71401
Quatre Bornes   -20.2654    57.4778 Plaine Wilhems  73304
Vacoas  -20.2981    57.4783 Plaine Wilhems  50810
Mahebourg   20.4081 57.7000 Grand Port  72249
Goodlands   -20.0350    57.6431 Rivere du Rempart   72201

City    Lat Long    District    Postcode
------------------------------------------------------------
Beau Bassin -20.2276    57.4681 Plaine Wilhems  71401
Curepipe    -20.3162    57.5166 Plaine Wilhems  74415
Ebene   -20.2456    57.4842 Plaine Wilhems  30401
Goodlands   -20.0350    57.6431 Rivere du Rempart   72201
Mahebourg   20.4081 57.7000 Grand Port  72249
Quatre Bornes   -20.2654    57.4778 Plaine Wilhems  73304
Rose Hill   -20.2456    57.4719 Plaine Wilhems  71360
Vacoas  -20.2981    57.4783 Plaine Wilhems  50810
```